# Checking button click for particular class

Tags: jquery

```
$("div#buttonContainer ul li").live("click",function(){    
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
        alert('selected');
    }    
});

<div id="buttonContainer">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

I have the click handler that applies to all the li tags, but I want specific function to execute when the li has the selected class. The javascript above pops up the alert on any li clicked. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, perhaps I'm not targeting the specific li properly.

EDIT:

I must use jquery 1.3 techniques as I can't upgrade.

Comment: Use `on` instead of `live`, `live` is deprecated.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gxvac/

Comment: Have you tested this code? It works.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to use jquery 1.3.

Comment: my response for changing li to li.selected works even back on jQuery 1.3. :)

Comment: Yes I'm aware, but I want it to apply to all the li's. But for the selected li I want a different action.

Comment: Plugged your code from above into jsFiddle with jQuery set to 1.3.2 and it works just fine.

Comment: updated answer to take out this context ambiguity. Let us know if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other posters have responded the simple case is working in jsFiddle, I am going to assume that in your actual app something has changed the this context. So this solution will remove this from the picture and use the target of the click with live so it will still work in jQuery 1.3

```
$("#buttonContainer ul li").live("click",function(e){
  if($(e.target).hasClass('selected')){
    console.log('selected');
  }
  console.log('any li');
});
```

Comment: and I hope that div#buttonContainer is redundant :) #buttonContainer should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Works fine. But use `on()`... `live()` is deprecated.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/U7vPk/)

```
$(function() {
    $("div#buttonContainer ul").on("click", "li", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            alert('selected');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: But using `.on` like that only works if the `li` element is already in the DOM, which kinda makes the use of `.on` unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, your ORIGINAL answer was using `.on` in a way that required the element to be in the DOM, then an HOUR after I point that out, you edit your answer and tell me I'm wrong...

Comment: You made it sound like using on() couldn't be used with dynamically added elements. That's what I was pointing out. `on()` is necessary since `live()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I've switched to using `on()`, as `live()` is officially deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, that said:

```
$("#buttonContainer ul li").on("click", function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.hasClass('selected')) {
        alert('selected');
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ad4vw/).